# EditText, when setting to maxLines = 1 and enter is pressed it erases and crashes

Tags: android

I have an issue regarding the EditText. Doing a simple math game where the player will get an example such as this: 9 x 9 = __ . The empty space (= EditText, limited to only numbers) is where the player has to fill in correct answer from the equation and press an [ CORRECT ]-button to correct the equation.

**Problem:**
I have currently set `android.maxLines = "1"`. Now each time the player presses the Enter-key any written text will be erased. If you re-type back and press the Correct-button the app stopps working. However, for as long as you don't press enter the app works just fine using the Correct-button. How do I prevent it from crashing/stop working? But also stop it from erasing any numbers when pressing the Enter-key.

**XML-file:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_play"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.laboration2.EasyActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textEasyMultiply"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textEasyNumber1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:text="@string/multiply"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textEasyNumber1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/answerButton"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/answerButton"
        android:text="@string/number_1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textEasyEqual"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textEasyNumber1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="@string/equal"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextEasyResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textEasyEqual"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="    "
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textEasyScore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/answerButton"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/answerButton"
        android:text="@string/score_0"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/answerButton"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextEasyResult"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:text="@string/button_result"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textEasyNumber2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textEasyEqual"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textEasyLevel"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textEasyLevel"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="@string/number_2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textEasyLevel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textEasyScore"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textEasyScore"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/answerButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/answerButton"
        android:text="@string/level_0"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**JAVA-file:**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.answerButton:
            int easyNum1 = Integer.parseInt(textEasyNumber1.getText().toString());
            int easyNum2 = Integer.parseInt(textEasyNumber2.getText().toString());
            int easyResult = Integer.parseInt(editTextEasyResult.getText().toString());
            if(easyNum1 * easyNum2 == easyResult){
                currentScore++;
                currentLevel++;
                textEasyScore.setText("Score: " + currentScore);
                textEasyLevel.setText("Level: " + currentLevel);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Good job!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                editTextEasyResult.setText("");
            }else{
                currentScore = 0;
                currentLevel = 0;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wrong! :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            //Updates Scores & Level
            textEasyScore.setText("Score: " + currentScore);
            textEasyLevel.setText("Level: " + currentLevel);
            break;
    }//switch ends here

    //stores the Score into the High Score page, when new High Score is reached it will auto-update
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefsHighScore = getSharedPreferences("Prefs_HighScore",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editorScore = sharedPrefsHighScore.edit();
    int storedHighScore = sharedPrefsHighScore.getInt("highScore",0);
    if (currentScore>storedHighScore) {
        editorScore.putInt("highScore", currentScore);
        editorScore.commit();

        //if a new High Score is achieved, the toastmessage "NEW HIGH SCORE!" will be shown (with modifications)
        Toast highScoreToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NEW HIGH SCORE!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            TextView toastMessage = (TextView) highScoreToast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
            toastMessage.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            toastMessage.setTextSize(25);
        highScoreToast.show();
    }//if-statement ends here

    randomNumbersForEquation();
}//onClick ends here


//adds a random number for our Equation (for textEasyNumber1 and textEasyNumber2)
void randomNumbersForEquation(){
    int addingOneTocurrentLevel = currentLevel + 1;
    int numberRange = addingOneTocurrentLevel * 3;
    Random randInt = new Random();

    int Number1 = randInt.nextInt(numberRange);
    Number1++;//don't want a zero value

    int Number2 = randInt.nextInt(numberRange);
    Number2++;//don't want a zero value

    textEasyNumber1.setText("" + Number1);
    textEasyNumber2.setText("" + Number2);
}//setQuestion ends here
```

Comment: post the crash log...

Comment: @rafsanahmad007: Here's the Crash log:

Comment: @rafsanahmad007: Here's the Crash log: [link]http://sv.tinypic.com/r/29bylw2/9

Comment: Found the problem to this. However, don't know how to solve it. The problem arises when you press enter, just like Sagar Das stated below the number will shift up and be out of sight. This also creates a space. If the space isn't removed/deleted before pressing the "Correct-button", the app stopps working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these together

```
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLines="1"
```

Comment: I'm using Numbers as `inputType` to prevent text from being written. Does it work with numbers as well? EDIT: just realised I hadn't put the `inputType` after I did a swap between a TextView & EditText. Lets try with that as well.

Comment: Works good now. I also have the settings above and no further problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you press "enter" key, the text doesn't get erased, rather it shifts up. After hitting enter key, press the up arrow key and you will find your text. The problem might be with the logic you have  written for "Correct" button. Please share the code which is executed upon pressing "Correct" button

UPDATED --- Try using trim() method to remove trailing spaces. Since you are parsing the value into an int, the extra space might be causing the issue Something like this:

```
Integer.parseInt(editTextEasyResult.getText().toString().trim());
```

Another suggestion is, since you are developing a maths related app, you can restrict your EditText to accept numbers only. Do so by mentioning the following attribute for your edit text file:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Doing so will present a numerical keyboard to the user without the enter key.

Comment: Updated the onClick codes related to the "Correct-button".

Comment: Found the problem to this. However, don't know how to solve it. The problem arises when you press enter, just like you stated the number will shift up and be out of sight. This also creates a space. If the space isn't removed/deleted before pressing the "Correct-button", the app stopps working.

Comment: The `trim()` prevents the app from crashing/stop working. How do I completely stop it from going up when I press the Enter-key?

Comment: try adding android:inputType="number" attributte to your EditText in xml file

Comment: Was just about to do that. Just realised I hadn't added that after I did a swap between this EditText (who used to be a TextView) and another TextView (who used to be my EditText). It works perfectly now. I just have 1 little issue. When I type in wrong answere in my calculation, it doesn't clear out the text. Only if the answere is correct. Before it used to erase no matter right or wrong.

Comment: This is what worked for me in case anyone have the same problem with text going up and giving errors and crashes:
no need for `.trim()`. This solved it all:
          `android:imeOptions="actionDone"
          android:inputType="number"
          android:maxLines="1"`